# Access to keychain from interactive UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, keychain, interactive

I'm working on an app that ask the user at specific times if he or she is at the office today through an interactive local notification. There are then two buttons, specifying where the user will be. This will trigger a piece of code that send a message to Slack, using the unique token for that user. This token is stored in the KeyChain.

```
func sendMessageAsUser(message: String) {
    if (TegKeychain.get("token") != nil)
    {
        let bericht = "&text=" + message
        let token = "token=" + TegKeychain.get("token")
        let channelID = "&channel=" + "redacted"

        let str =   token +
                channelID +
                bericht +
                "&as_user=true"
        self.sendMessage(str, url: "https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage")
    }
    else
    {
        println("No token entered yet!")
    }
}
```

Now I found out that if the user is on the lockscreen, they need to enter authenticate first (Pin/password/touchID) before the message can be send. This makes sense from a security perspective, that notifications are sandboxed and cannot access the keychain if the device is locked.

From userfriendliness perspective however, it takes an extra interaction that is cumbersome. **So my question is, how can I post the message to Slack using the token from the keychain without compromising security?** (For example, storing the token in NSUserDefaults would be bad idea)